# DataGrid - Event which fires after CellEditEnding()

Tags: c#, wpf, events, datagridview

I have a `DataGrid` associated with a `List <>` of objects (`ItemsSource`). In the `CellEditEnding ()` event, I change the data of the linked object list. To refresh the `DataGrid`, it must be refreshed:

```
this.DataGridFieldProperties.Items.Refresh();
```

Invoking the update from code within  the `CellEditEnding()` event throws an `InvalidOperationException`.

**Question:**
Is there an event triggered after CellEditEnding()?

**What I have tried so far**
Multiple events, such as `GotFocus`, `ColumnDisplayIndexChanged()`, etc., and two-way bindings. But none of them works reliably and refreshing the `DataGrid` in an asynchronous thread (async event with `Task.Run()`)

**Example**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Name="Btn_FillGrid" Click="Btn_FillGrid_Click"/>
    <DataGrid Name="DataGrid_SOExample" Grid.Row="1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" IsReadOnly="False" CellEditEnding="DataGrid_SOExample_CellEditEnding">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Generic1"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Generic2"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>



public partial class Win_SOExample : Window
{
    public Win_SOExample()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Btn_FillGrid_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<SoExample> soExampList = new List<SoExample>();
        soExampList.Add(new SoExample() { Field1 = "Row0 Field1", Field2 = "Row0 Field2" });
        soExampList.Add(new SoExample() { Field1 = "Row1 Field1", Field2 = "Row1 Field2" });
        soExampList.Add(new SoExample() { Field1 = "Row2 Field1", Field2 = "Row2 Field2" });

        (this.DataGrid_SOExample.Columns[0] as DataGridTextColumn).Binding = new Binding("Field1") { Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay };
        (this.DataGrid_SOExample.Columns[1] as DataGridTextColumn).Binding = new Binding("Field2") { Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay };
        this.DataGrid_SOExample.ItemsSource = soExampList;
    }

    private async void DataGrid_SOExample_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.EditAction == DataGridEditAction.Commit)
        {
            // after the user finished the edit, data in other rows needs to get updatet

            // simple example
            List<SoExample> soExampList = (this.DataGrid_SOExample.ItemsSource as List<SoExample>);
            soExampList[1].Field1 = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString();

            await Task.Yield();
            this.DataGrid_SOExample.Items.Refresh();
        }
    }

    private class SoExample
    {
        public string Field1 { get; set; } = "";
        public string Field2 { get; set; } = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try an async event handler and await Task.Yield(); before refresh code?

Comment: @SirRufo I didn't think about that ..... but now I tried ... same behaviour.

Comment: Can you post a [MCVE]?

Comment: What does "change the data of the linked object list" really mean? What are you trying to do and why?

Comment: `await Task.Run(() => DataGrid_SOExample.Items.Refresh());` should throw an exception. use `DataGrid_SOExample.Items.Refresh();` instead.

Comment: @SirRufo Already tried, both attempts throw `system.invalidoperationexception 'refresh' is not allowed during an addnew or edititem transaction`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your `SoExample` class:

```
private class SoExample : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _field1;
    public string Field1
    {
        get { return _field1; }
        set { _field1 = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private string _field2;
    public string Field2
    {
        get { return _field2; }
        set { _field2 = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Then you can set the property to a new value without refreshing:

```
private async void DataGrid_SOExample_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.EditAction == DataGridEditAction.Commit)
    {
        List<SoExample> soExampList = (this.DataGrid_SOExample.ItemsSource as List<SoExample>);
        soExampList[1].Field1 = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString();
    }
}
```